# How to extract files inside a directory from a tar file in terminal?

Tags: unix, terminal, extract, tar

I want to extract only the files inside a folder of a tar file

Example:

Contents of tar file:

- `/home/parent_dir/child_dir/`

I want to extract only the files inside child_dir to another directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `cd <another_directory>`
>   `tar xvf <path_to_tar>/<tarfile>.tar <child_dir>`
>   e.g.
>   `cd <parent_directory>`
>   `tar cvf test.tar *`
>   `tar tf test.tar`
>   see the folder you wanted. e.g. `src/org`
>   `cd <some other directory you want to extract to>`
>   `tar xvf ..\test.tar src/org`
>   `ls`
>   you'll now see the directory you were after from the tar e.g. `src/org`

Answer (score 9):

The command

```
tar xf tarfile.tar /home/parent_dir/child_dir
```

will only extract files in `child_dir` and its subordinates.

If `/home/parent_dir/child_dir` is not where you want them to be, [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) provides a `--transform` option that would be used like:

```
tar  --transform 's,/home/parent_dir/child_dir,foo,' --show-transformed -xf tarfile.tar
```

which will put the files that would have gone into `/home/parent_dir/child_dir` into `./foo` instead.